# @ in regex (at-sign)

Tags: java, regex

I can't use @ in a regex?
For example:  `(?is).*\bhello\b.*` matches `hello`, but
`(?is).*\b@hello\b.*` doesn't match `@hello`.

Here's some examples. [This](http://regex101.com/r/kD8vT4) works, but [this](http://regex101.com/r/iF7yH6) doesn't work.

Can someone explain to me why? Oh, also, [this](http://regex101.com/r/jB4gM7) doesn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of `\b` (word boundary).

`\b` matches between a `\w` and a `\W` character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning/end of the string. But `@` is not `\w` character (while `h` is `\w` character). So no match.

Comment: What's a way to get past this?

Comment: @DoorKnob, Remove `\b` before `@`.

Comment: that will then match, for example, `hi@hello`. I don't want it to do that.

Comment: @DoorKnob, Try `(^|\W)@hello`.

Comment: but then, `String.matches()` doesn't match `hi @hello`. Sorry, I'm just a bit confused.

Edit: nevermind, I got it. `.*(^|\W)@hello`

Comment: Why \b matches after @ while \b is placed before @ ?

Comment: @JCH77, I don't get it. Could you post a separated question with concrete example so others can answer you?

Comment: I am adding a regex validation for alphanumerical input in ASP.NET and C# app. I found the regex to be the following "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$". Is there a difference between this and putting an at sign at the beginning of it? Like this: @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"

Comment: @naz786, It's [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim). It make easy escape sequences are interpreted literally. For the given regular expression, there's no escape character, so no difference between them.